# When running Sidekiq via systemd, where are the logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, systemd

The title of the question pretty much says it.

If it helps for some reason, here's my `ExecStart` directive:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec sidekiq -e production
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Systemd unit logs can be accessed with `journalctl`.

Assuming that Sidekiq's unit name is sidekiq, you can get its logs with the following command:

```
journalctl -u sidekiq
```

You can also append `-f` to the command to continuously get new log entries.

```
journalctl -u sidekiq -f
```

Check `journalctl --help` for more useful options.

Comment: Thanks. The `-f` flag was the key thing for me.